# How to order data in a dynamic SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, pivot-table

I do have a Dynamic SQL statement because I need to pivot my data on a specific column. I am able to order my columns according to a specific column id that I created, but my problem is that I am not able to order the data in the output set.

```
DECLARE @PivotTableSQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL2 = N'
  Select ''regionMailMerge'',''tblTransactions''

  SELECT nasParticipant, nomParticipant, prenomParticipant, dateTransaction,typeTransaction,'+@PivotColumnHeaders+'
  FROM (
    SELECT top 10000
      H.nasParticipant,
      H.nomParticipant,
      H.prenomParticipant,
      H.dateTransaction,
      H.profil,
      H.ValeurTransaction,
      H.idTri,
      h.typeTransaction
    FROM T_SommaireRapportTransactions H
    ORDER BY H.nomParticipant, H.prenomParticipant
  ) AS PivotData
  PIVOT (
    SUM(ValeurTransaction)
    FOR profil IN (
      ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
    )
  ) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY idTri'


EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL2)
```

My query works, but the data is not ordered by nomParticipant, prenomParticipant. I also tried without the TOP 10000, but I keep receiving the following error :

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help, I searched the web and wasn't able to find a proper answer for my problem.

Comment: `ORDER BY H.nomParticipant, H.prenomParticipant` must be in the end of query, where `ORDER BY idTri` stands now.

Comment: i tried that as well but I received the following error:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
The multi-part identifier "PivotData.nomParticipant" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
The multi-part identifier "PivotData.prenomParticipant" could not be bound.

Comment: Oh! I removed the alias and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Samuel See my answer on **[SQL Server Query Error -ORDER BY clause is invalid in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697511/sql-server-query-error-order-by-clause-is-invalid-in-views/61702593#61702593)**.